# What is the geometric way of relating zero to infinity?

Tags: geometry, infinity

I once saw (what I think was) a geometric way a relating zero to infinity.  Something about a circle with radius 1 around the origin.    Can you tell me where to find that?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the stereographic projection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection

Answer (score 2):

In the Riemann sphere, the complex plane augmented with a point at infinity, you can make the substitution $w=\frac 1z$.  Each point is "reflected across the unit circle" and $\infty \leftrightarrow 0$